# Add url extensions to Laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel, url-rewriting, laravel-routing

Is it possible to add an extension to laravel routes like so?

`http://www.mywebsite.com/members/login.html`

and another page with a different extension

`http://www.mywebsite.com/contactus.htm`

I am transitioning an old website into laravel but the owner doesn't want to change the URL for SEO purposes.

Comment: This should be done with Apache's `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is certainly possible  and very straightforward to do with Laravel.

**routes.php:**

```
Route::get('members/login.html', function() { return View::make('members.login'); } );
```

Then you need to create the view **members/login.php** or **members/login.blade.php** in your `views` directory.

Comment: what if there is optional url parameter at the end of url like:
`Route::get('foo/{bar?}', function () {});`
And I want to generate urls like these; `domain.com/foo.html` and `domain.com/foo/bar.html`

Comment: This is still a very useful answer even after 9 years. Thanks @Simo

Answer (score 2):

```
Route::get('{id}-{another_id}.html', 'Controller@view')
        ->where('id', '.*?')
        ->where('another_id', '\d+');
```

Something like this