# Laravel routes ending with '.php' not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, url-routing

Using Laravel, I want to create a route to replace functionality of a legacy URL that used to be a PHP file, but whenever I create a route that ends with `.php` it does not recognize the route and I get a 404.

`Route::get('test.php', function(){return "test";}); // Gets a 404  error.`

However other routes with extensions seem to work.

`Route::get('test.txt', function(){return "test";}); // works fine`

Comment: Still interested in finding solution to the question above, use this link and choose the first answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287649/add-url-extensions-to-laravel-routes

Answer (score 2):

see [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) as its a part of apache mod_rewrite handling this, not the laravel framework alone. see into public/.htaccess file .

I don't see any reason to do this. But as you want to know i am telling. I don't recommend this as its avoiding some purposes of the framework.

At first what you need to do is edit your .htaccess file rewrite rules to enable php extension. i can't say much as i don't see those files here.

Second thing is that all requests will be by default redirected to index.php . see one of my laravel project public/ folder .htaccess file. **you need to look into yours and modify that, there is lot of ways you can modify according to your needs. there could be other .htaccess files**

*for extension changing part look here*

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` *part for changing index.php*

my .htaccess file as it is not modified

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Answer (score -3):

In laravel your routes do not need a .php extension.

check out the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-parameters).

Also when you return views you do not need the .php extension.

Comment: I know. There is an URL that already exist that I want to replace with a route in laravel. I cannot change the URL due to legacy support and it ends with `.php`.