# Laravel: How to allow routes with php extensions?

Tags: nginx, laravel-5

In my laravel application I wants to allow routes with .php extensions like:

```
xyz.com/some/random/url.php
```

If I just add it as a normal route then I get error **No input file specified.**

It works fine with ***php artisan serve*** but not with production nginx server. I think I've to change something at nginx config or .htaccess file but not sure.

Does anyone has any idea or hint how I can do this?

Comment: URIs ending with `.php` are usually handled by a specific `location` block in a typical Nginx configuration. You current configuration is guilty of [sending uncontrolled requests to PHP](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php). Both issues can probably be fixed with the addition of a `try_files` statement. For specific help, please edit your question and add your Nginx configuration file containing the relevant `server { ... }` block.

Comment: If anyone is still interested in finding solution to the question above, use this link and choose the very first answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287649/add-url-extensions-to-laravel-routes